# return int for the image shows in screen?

Tags: java, android

I have an android app which i'm building with android studio and I need your help. I will simplify my question:
if we say that the app has two images (image 1 and 2), wheras only one image is displayed on screen and to change the image displayed we use a next button.

I need a code that returns int to the image that is shown on the screen, which 
I will use in my if statement:

```
if (R.id.imageView1 == ) {
```

Comment: you put the image on the screen, therefore you should ALREADY know what "int" represents that iamge.

Comment: @Ahmed It's not clear what you are asking

Comment: Once you hit next, it's showing the second image. Remember that ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make an index to keep track of it to know what image you are showing.

```
int currentImage = 1;
```

In your button labeled `next` increment the currentImage

```
currentImage++;
```

Then you can do

```
if (currentImage == 1) // We are showing first image
else if(currentImage == 2) // Second image
...
```